# Nodejs on heavy load

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using nodejs with `socket.io` on my chat system. My hardware is `13.6 Ghz Cpu` and `16gb ram`.

When the online users count reaches `600`,some users can't connect to socket,can't send messages.And some users disconnects from chat.

How can I resolve this problem ? What is your opinion of this problem ?

Comment: What is your available network bandwidth? What is the typical throughput of the network from the service provider? What is the negotiated "speed" on the NIC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect can't connect error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391432/how-can-i-detect-cant-connect-error)

Comment: @zamnuts I have unlimited bandwidth.Maybe server have max connected ip limit ? I am using centOs What do you think about ?

Comment: @TolgayToklar there is no such thing as unlimited bandwidth. There is a physical maximum on everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I'm not sure how you have a clock speed of 13.6ghz for a single thread. I'd assume your CPU has multiple cores, or your mobo supports multiple processor sockets, and 13.6 is simply a sum. ([8.2GHz was a *world record*](http://hwbot.org/submission/2406060_the_stilt_cpu_frequency_a10_6800k_8203_mhz) that was set July 23rd, 2013.)

Secondly, I'd ask yourself *why* the disconnect is happening.

- Are you watching processor load - is a single thread maxing out its processor allocation (i.e. 100% usage on a single core)?
- How's your RAM consumption; is it climbing, and has the OS offloaded
  memory onto the page file/swap partition - could there be a memory
  leak?
- Is your network bandwidth capped? Has it reached its maximum capacity?

My high-level recommendations are:

- Make sure your application is non-blocking. This means using asynchronous methods whenever possible. By design, however, all Node.js' Net methods are asynchronous.
- Consider clustering your application and use a shared port. This is possible with Node.js child processes using [Cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). This will distribute the load on the CPU to multiple cores. You don't have to worry about load balancing (e.g. round-robin, fastest, ratio) - handling the client is on a first-available first-serve basis, whichever Node.js process can handle the client's request first, wins.
- Verify your NIC has enough throughput to handle the load. If it is configured for / auto-negotiating as 10BASE-T or 100BASE-TX half-duplex, you could be in trouble.

Ultimately, you need to perform more diagnostics to isolate the issue. **Curiosity**, digging, patience and research will lead you to the answer. Your question is far too open-ended to be provided with an exact answer - it is more theoretical. There are also too many variables to pinpoint an exact cause.

Comment: I researched this problem,and guess I found it.Server ram usage 15.6/16gb at yesterday,and some users can't connect to socket.At today ram usage 3.3gb and everbody can connect to socket.How can I reduce ram usage ?

Comment: @TolgayToklar 15.6gb for a chat server is enormous. this symptom definitely points to a memory leak. there are plenty of resources on the interwebs that show how to perform memory profiling of node, although some are archaic and no longer work. you could also diagnose by stepping through your code via a debugger to see how objects are initialized, write to a log file, or simply read through it very carefully. I couldn't tell you where the memory leak is without seeing the application in its entirety.

Comment: I see.I think problem is the cached memory.It was too big.When I clean up the cached memory,real ram usage returned to 3-4gb.Can I close the ram cache ?

Comment: @TolgayToklar your ram cache shouldn't be a problem. this is completely passive in linux (see http://www.linuxatemyram.com/). i would be more concerned with your real ram usage at 3-4gb... how much of that is your application? Did you monitor your applications ram usage? is it constantly increasing? Does it ever go down? did you try doing a heap profile on the node.js process? what about monitoring with nagios/zabbix - check the ram usage over a larger timeline.

Comment: I checked nodejs's ram usage 600mb,mysql's 1gb,apache's 500mb